# twitter followers in R returns error in cat

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to get the twitter user and their following using R.
Code is running fine in R but getting error when trying to create shiny App for this. Error is:

**Warning: Error in cat: argument 1 (type 'closure') cannot be handled by 'cat'**
in below code

**server.R**

```
    shinyServer(function(input, output) {
      rawData <- reactive({
        follow <- Reduce(intersect,
  list(getUser(input$User1)$getFriendIDs(),getUser(input$User2)$getFriendIDs()))
              follow <- list(follow)
            })
          output$table <- renderText({rawData()})
        })
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel("t n"),
  sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(textInput("User1", "What to Search"),
                  (textInput("User2", "U2 to Search")),
                  submitButton(text = "Run")),

      mainPanel(
       textOutput("table")
    )
  )
))
```

Comment: I think you are trying to enclose a reactive statement within another reactive statement which is why you are getting this error. Can you confirm by posting more of your code?

Comment: can you please elaborate it....and thats the only code i have.

Comment: You said it works fine in R. Can you post the code you had that was not in Shiny as well as some data for us to try?

Comment: In the following snippet: "getUser(input$User1)$getFriendIDs()" Where are you defining the functions getUser or getFriendsIDs? Either appear to also be reactive statements which you are then calling inside another reactive statement "rawData <- reactive({...})".

Comment: If you run this code it works fins: #Get 1st user following
user1 <- getUser("keshavchhn")
following1 <- user1$getFriendIDs()

#Get 2nd user following
user2 <- getUser("....any user")
following2 <- user2$getFriendIDs()

#Common Following

ids <- Reduce(intersect, list(following1,following2))

Comment: i got it..prob is with the function only..thanks man :-)

Comment: You should post your solution as the answer then

Comment: sure but now getting a new error sometimes..any ideaError in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(paste("users", "show", sept = "/"), params = params, :

Comment: shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  RD <- reactive({  
    #Get 1st user following
    
    if(input$User1 == " ") {
      return(NULL)
    }
    user1 <- getUser(input$User1)
    
    following1 <- user1$getFriendIDs()
    
    #Get 2nd user following
    if(input$User2 == " ") {
      return(NULL)
    }
    user2 <- getUser(input$User2)
    following2 <- user2$getFriendIDs()
    
    #Common Following
    
    ids <- Reduce(intersect, list(following1,following2))